# how to add dummy SMSs to android avd?

Tags: android, sms, android-virtual-device

I am trying to build an app that accesses the sms on android os.
But i dont have an android device.. so how to add some dummy sms on to the avd so that i can test my app on those sms?? or any other way out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DDMS there is a tab named "Emulator Control" you can send SMSs or Calls to the emulator from there